# Is using clojure's stm as a global state considered a good practice?

Tags: clojure

in most of my clojure programs... and alot other clojure programs I see, there is some sort of global variable in an atom:

```
(def *program-state* 
   (atom {:name  "Program"
          :var1  1
          :var2  "Another value"}))
```

And this state would be referred to occasionally in the code.

```
(defn program-name []
    (:name @*program-state*))
```

Reading this article http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/24/how-to-write-3v1l-untestable-code/ made me rethink global state but somehow, even though I completely agree with the article, I think its okay to use hash-maps in atoms because its providing a common interface for manipulating global state data (analogous to using different databases to store your data).

I would like some other thoughts on this matter.

Comment: No, it's not a good practice.  Avoid it like the plague.  If you have to do it, then try to minimize the amount of code that touches it or knows about.  Global state is the enemy of modularity and composability.  It couples code, making it difficult to refactor or fix.

Comment: You need to have some global state if you want to be able to interact with the program through a repl though. Of course you don't actually have to tell your main program that the state is exposed globally, and it's better to program as if it wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing can be OK, but it is also often a design smell so I would approach with caution.

Things to think about:

- **Consistency** - can one part of the code change the program name? if so then the `program-name` function will behave inconsistently from the perspective of other threads. Not good!
- **Testability** - is this easy to test? can one part of the test suite that is changing the program name safely run concurrently with another test that is reading the name?
- **Multiple instances** - will you ever have two different parts of the application expecting to use a different program-name at the same time? If so, this is a strong hint that your mutable state should not be global.

Alternatives to consider:

- Using a **ref instead of an atom**, you can at least ensure consistency of mutable state within transactions
- Using **binding** you can limit mutability to a per-thread basis. This solves most of the concurrency issues and can be helpful when your global variables are being used like a set of thread-local configuration parameters.
- Using **immutable global state** wherever you can. Does it really need to be mutable?

Comment: +1 for the Multiple instances comment :) Not planning for needing two global states creates creeping problems...

Answer (score 2):

I think having a single global state that is occasionally updated in commutative ways is fine. When you start having two global states that need to be updated and threads start using them for communication, then I start to worry.

- maintaining a count of current global users is fine:

  - Any thread can inc or dec this at any time without hurting another
  - If it changes out from under your thread nothing explodes.
- maintaining the log directory is questionable:

  - When it changes will all threads stop writing to the old one?
  - if two threads change it will they converge.
- Using this as a message queue is even more dubious:

Comment: thanks! what are your thoughts on this article: http://gen5.info/q/2008/07/25/the-multiton-design-pattern/

Comment: @zcaudate: This article is a typical OO article about "just another design pattern"... I would suggest.. don't do that :)

Comment: How would you implement a message queue then? I'm not entirely sure whether or not I'll need this right now, but I believe with my current project I'm sooner or later gonna run into a situation in which I need  a message queue (i.e. from an IO thread getting key presses to a thread handling logic).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fine to have such a global state (and in many cases it is required) but I would be careful about that the core logic of my application have functions that take the state as a parameter and return the updated state rather than directly accessing the global state. Basically I would prefer to have a controlled access to the global state from few set of function and everything else in my program should use these set of methods to access the state as that would allow me to abstract away the state implementation i.e initially I could start with an in memory atom, then may be move to some persistent storage.